# Error Cannot POST /url/ NodeJS, Express MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mongodb, express

estoy haciendo una API Rest con NodeJS, realmente soy nueva en esto y no sé donde está el problema. Mediante Postman trato de enviarle a la ruta /signup/ email y password por Json pero me devuelve en formato HTML Error Cannot POST /signup/.  He visto que a algunas personas les pasaba que debían importar body-parser, pero yo ya lo tengo importado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Este es mi app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const verifyToken = require('./middlewares/auth');

const productsRouter = require('./routes/products');
const ordersRouter = require('./routes/orders');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const app = express();


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//  Configurar --> CORS
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Permitir acceso a todos los dominios
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Athorization');
 if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
   return res.status(200).json({});
 }
 next();
});

app.use('/products', verifyToken, productsRouter);
app.use('/orders', verifyToken, ordersRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


module.exports = app;
```

Aca les dejo mi github para que puedan ver mi codigo entero https://github.com/virginiasacudato/API-REST-NODEJS

Desde ya, mil gracias.

Comment: En ninguna parte de tu código tienes el manejo para solicitudes tipo `POST` a la ruta `/signup`. Es por ello que te muestra ese mensaje de error. En cuanto al código de tu repositorio, tienes bastantes problemas, es normal si estás iniciando en esto. Trataré de responder tu pregunta basado en el código de tu `repo` o lo que muestras en tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Creo que el es mejor cerrar la pregunta por error tipográfico. Resulta que haces una solicitud `POST` a la ruta `/signup`, pero realmente debes hacerlo a la ruta `/users/signup` que es lo que maneja realmente el envío de datos desde el cliente. Tal como digo en mi comentario anterior, no tienes un manejador para la ruta `/signup`, pero si tienes uno para la ruta `/users/signup`. Saludos

Comment: Mil gracias 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo visto tu error se debe a que en tu **app.js** haces referencia a la ruta **/users**

```
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

el cual contiene una funcion donde especificas dos metodos **POST**
con las rutas **/signup**  y **/login**

```
router.post('/signup', loginValidation, usersController.signup);
```

por lo tanto tu peticion a tu api deberia ser **http://localhost:3900/users/signup**

Comment: Mil gracias 